# Was Bruce Bruce in So Fresh, So Clean?

Tags: rap

tl;dr: Was Bruce Bruce in So Fresh, So Clean?

Having said that, I feel I have to put some backstory in this question.

As a teenager I was a huge fan of Bruce Bruce from BET Comic View. I ended up running into Bruce Bruce at the ATL airport a few years ago, as we both waited for the "plane train" to take us to baggage claim. I didn't say anything to him for the first 20 minutes, to give him respect and privacy (even though it was just he and I at first, waiting on the train). On the elevator up to baggage claim, however, he stood behind me and I had to give him some compliments.

I mentioned the Outkast video "So fresh, so clean". I'm 99% sure that was him in the video, but could you confirm it?

There's some small chance I might get to holler at him again when he has a show in my town this Fall, and I just want to make sure I got that detail correct, in case it comes up again. I just watched the video and it certainly looks like the way I remember him, but on his website he looks a little different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1049593/), he plays the Pastor.
I checked, he appears arround [3:08](https://youtu.be/-JfEJq56IwI?t=188), he wears a pink suit.